# Azure Data Factory CI/CD Improvements integrated with DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-data-factory

I've been reading the following link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/continuous-integration-delivery-improvements
It mentions using npm to build the Data Factory ARM templates and use the resulting artefact to deploy to UAT/Prod etc instead of using the adf_publish branch.

Has anyone got a sample Yaml file that does this?

Also, how would you handle overriding the ARM Template Parameters Json file for changing over parameterization such as the Environments Key Vault etc e.g. Dev-KV -> UAT-KV, Prod-KV

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did.  I followed this article to get my yaml file setup, there is a github repo in the article that has all of this persons code.
[Azure Data Factory CI-CD made simple: Building and deploying ARM templates with Azure DevOps YAML Pipelines](https://towardsdatascience.com/azure-data-factory-ci-cd-made-simple-building-and-deploying-your-arm-templates-with-azure-devops-30c30595afa5)

Then I used Global parameters and referenced those everywhere in my pipelines.  Here is a ref for that: [Global parameters in Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/author-global-parameters)

And finally, I used the overrideParameters option in my yaml pipeline to deploy the correct version of the parameter to the correct environment.  Here is a ref for that:  [ADF Release - Set global params during deployment](https://microsoft-bitools.blogspot.com/2021/11/adf-snack-set-global-params-during.html)

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks - I saw the first link previously, the final two really help to flesh it out.